# Updating Error in many to many relationships in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many

In my .Net Core project i have two models with many-to many relationships:

```
public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
        public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<BookPublicHouse> BookPublicHouses { get; set; }

        public Book()
        {
            BookPublicHouses = new Collection<BookPublicHouse>();
        }

    }



public class PublicHouse
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookPublicHouse> BookPublicHouses { get; set; }

    public PublicHouse()
    {
        BookPublicHouses = new Collection<BookPublicHouse>();
    }
}
```

And join table for EF Core:

```
 public class BookPublicHouse
    {
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Book_Id")]
        public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Author_Id")]
        public virtual PublicHouse PublicHouse { get; set; }

        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }
    }
```

Context:

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
    {
        public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<BookPublicHouse>().HasKey(bp => new { bp.BookId, bp.PublicHouseId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<BookPublicHouse>()
                .HasOne(bp => bp.Book)
                .WithMany(b => b.BookPublicHouses)
                .HasForeignKey(bp => bp.BookId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BookPublicHouse>()
                .HasOne(bp => bp.PublicHouse)
                .WithMany(p => p.BookPublicHouses)
                .HasForeignKey(bp => bp.PublicHouseId);
        }
    }
```

In my BookRepository i have CRUD operations. But when I'm trying to update my instance of Book which include Public Houses, I have an exception: 'The instance of entity type 'Book' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'BookId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

Here is my Update method:

```
public void Update(Book book)
        {

            _dbContext.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

I'm trying some others cases:

In this method my list of PublicHouses don't changing:

```
 public void Update(Book book)
        {
             var current = Get(book.BookId);
            _dbContext.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(book);

        }

 public Book Get(int id)
        {
            return _dbContext.Books
                .Include(b => b.BookPublicHouses)
                .ThenInclude(bph => bph.PublicHouse).FirstOrDefault(x => x.BookId == id);
        }
```

In this case I have the same exception. Where is my problem?

```
public void Update(Book book)
        {
            var current = Get(book.BookId);
            _dbContext.Books.Remove(current);
            _dbContext.Add(book);
        }
```

Comment: What about if you don't set `_dbContext.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;` explicitly. As per your Get code you are fetching record without `AsNoTracking` enabled so that means you would be working on direct database represented entity, and EF would track the changes automatically. Also can you please post how are you defining the `modelBuilder Entity` for `Book` and `PublicHouse`?

Comment: Yet another reason to not use the repository pattern with EF. The repository pattern is for working with *SQL*, not an ORM. An ORM like Entity Framework *already* implements the repository and unit of work patterns. Particularly here, EF does all sorts of change tracking, caching, etc. to enable features and performance. Unless you handle everything just right in your repository, you have a good chance of jacking that up, leading to errors like this. Now, you're finding yourself debugging a useless abstraction, meaning that's time you aren't building the actual app you care about.

Comment: Ditch the repository and just use EF directly.

Comment: Just look at your quite enigmatic last code snippet. You remove a book and add the same thing again: that's attached twice.